# CSS-ReactJS Animation when an element gets visible

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I don't know if what I want is possible with pure CSS, I'd prefer to avoid using JQuery because I'm building my app with ReacJS.

I have the following effect

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 800ms ease-in;
  position: relative;
  right: calc(100px - 100%);
}

#chk:checked ~ #box{
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label>check the input to see the effect</label>
  <br/>
  <input id="chk" type="checkbox">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

It works when an input (checkbox) is checked, the thing is I want to reproduce the same effect but when an element is shown in the screen.

### Why not to use JQuery?

As I'm building my app using ReactJS, using JQuery is not recommended neither the community nor Facebook.

I'd like to use CSS some React component, but I don't know how.

### Check my own answer to see how I figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using CSS + ReactJS I solved doing this:

I used a checkbox to check or uncheck depending on where the scroll is. Then using CSS just change where the text is being rendered.

**CSS Code:**

```css
#WhoIAm-title {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all 800ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 800ms ease-in;
  transition: all 800ms ease-in;
  position: relative;
  right: -38%;
}

#WhoIAm-chk:checked ~ #WhoIAm-title {
  right: 38%;
}
```

**ReactJS Code:**

```js
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if (event.srcElement.body.scrollTop >= 620 && event.srcElement.body.scrollTop <= 650) {
      this.setState({ checked: true });
    }else if (event.srcElement.body.scrollTop >= 820 || event.srcElement.body.scrollTop <= 600) {
      this.setState({ checked: false });
    }
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div id="whoiam" className="Container column">
      <span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="WhoIAm-chk" style={{ display: "none" }} checked={this.state.checked} />
        <b id="WhoIAm-title">Title to toggle to right</b>
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just bind class to your animated box instead of binding state of checkbox. Don't know the react's syntax but in vue.js I would do it like this:

<div id="my-box" :class="{'is-animated' : box-visible}"></div>

Where box-visible is a boolean property like your "checked" state.

This would add a class to your box when box-visible is true and hide it when it returns false.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a class instead of selector with checked property and then toggle the class with react.

Comment: Really I cant figure out how to do it... have you got an example?

Comment: What do you don't know? How to write css to the class or how to toggle the class with react when element is visible?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nswnLq4d/1/ Here is fiddle with jQuery class toggle. You need to figure out how to detect if element is visible then add class to box element. That's all

Comment: Thanks, as I explained on my question, I prefer not using JQuery. Take a look at my own answer to see how I solved.